# Colouring one column of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe and would like to use the `.style` to highlight the first column.

I wasn't sure if there is a loop I have to use or a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need custom function which return `DataFrame` with color for first column:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

def highlight_col(x):
    r = 'background-color: red'
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.iloc[:, 0] = r
    return df1    
df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 18):

You can solve it in one line like this:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'red'}, subset=['A'])
```

where subset is the list of column names on which you want to apply the desired properties.

The result is the same as shown by @jezrael
You can check other properties and possibilities for styling [in pandas' website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Comment: With your one line of code, can you apply to several columns with different colors for each column?

Comment: @sqllearner you can apply the same color to several columns just by adding them to the subset, like df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'red'}, subset=['A', 'C']). But I'm not sure you can apply different colors on one line. set_properties according to the docs is : "for setting one or more non-data dependent properties".

Comment: @sqllearner you could solve it in two lines:    \  `col_ref = {'A': 'background-color: red', 'C':'background-color:yellow'}    \   df.style.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(col_ref, index=df.index, columns=df.columns).fillna(''), axis=None)`

Comment: Did this crash anyone else's notebook? Maybe my dataframe was too large (~1M rows).