# Color every other 2 columns of a dataframe into an excel?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a huge dataframe and I need to display it into an excel sheet such that every other 2 columns are colored except the 1st column.

For example:
If there are columns 1 to 100,
column 2,3 must be red
then 4,5 non colored
then 6,7 again red
then 8,9 non colored
and it goes on and on till last column of the `dataframe`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I came with following solution:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


columns = 13
data = np.array([np.arange(10)]*columns).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df = df.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})


for col in range(2, columns+1, 4):
    worksheet.set_column(col, col + 1, cell_format=format1)
    
writer.save()
```

Iterate from index 2 (second col), until `columns+1` (indexing comes from 1 in excel), color 2 cols at once and then move 4 indices further. The only problem here right now, it colors whole column (even not filled), I'll look for solution for that later.

Output:
[image: output]

You need to translate integer indices to excel-like labels with a function and use conditional_format in case you want to color only fields with text:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


columns = 13
data = np.array([np.arange(10)]*columns).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df = df.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})

def colnum_string(n):
    string = ""
    n+=1 #just because we have index saved in first col
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n - 1, 26)
        string = chr(65 + remainder) + string
    return string

for col in range(2, columns+1, 4):
    str1 = colnum_string(col)+"2" #ommiting header, 1 if header
    str2 = colnum_string(col+1)+str(11) #number of rows+1 (header)
    ids = str1+":"+str2
    print(ids)
    worksheet.conditional_format(ids, {'type': 'no_blanks',
                                     'format': format1})
    
writer.save()
```

Output of the second code:

[image: better output]

Answer (score 1):

In Excel,  Selected the columns containing you data or the entire spreadsheet.  Click Conditional formatting on the Home Ribbon.  Click New Rule.  Click Use a formula to determine which cells to format. In the formula box enter `=OR(MOD(COLUMN(A1),4)=2,MOD(COLUMN(A1),4)=3)`.  Click the Format button.  Select the fill tab.  Set the fill color to what you want. Hit OK a few times and you should be done.

This will fill in the cells that or equal to 2 or 3 mod 4.

Answer (score 0):

if you have poblem only with iteration than:

```
    for i in range(2, columns, 4):
        setColumnColor(i)
        setColumnColor(i+1)
```

You start coloring from the 2nd column and coloring 2 columns at a time. Than iterating on the columns by steps of 4.

But if you have problems on finding a method to set dataframe colors than this is a thread for you: [Colouring one column of pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388149/colouring-one-column-of-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You do it in Excel:

1. You start with converting a range to a table (Ctrl+T).
2. Then switch to the Design tab, remove a tick from Banded rows and select Banded columns instead.
   [image]
3. right-click on the table styles
   click on duplicates
   [image]

4. click on the first column stripe
5. on the stripe size insert 2
   note: you can click https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/03/13/alternate-row-column-colors-excel/#alternating-row-tables